# Proftpd : Allow users to see root

Tags: proftpd

I am setting up an FTP server and initially jailed all users in their home directory by using:

```
DefaultRoot ~
```

This behaviour causes the users to see only the contents of their home directories and nothing above it. For ex : When using a client such as filezilla and user as testuser, the testuser directory shows up as

```
/
incoming/
outgoing/
```

However I want to see if theres any way to allow users to 'see' the directories above it but not allowing them to list its contents, creating, deleting any files or directories . So using filezilla for testuser would be like:

```
/ftp
/home/
testuser/
incoming/
outgoing/
```

The only reason being is that currently we have automated pipelines that use the full path to get files i.e. `/ftp/home/testuser/dir/file.txt` which fails on my current config . However `/dir/file.txt` works just fine.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The best approach: adjust the automated pipelines. (of course..)

Another really simple (but still silly) one: create a relative symlink within the home, that should also work.

Ex:

```
mkdir -p /ftp/home/testuser/ftp/home
cd /ftp/home/testuser/ftp/home
ln -s ../../ testuser
ls -l /ftp/home/testuser/ftp/home/testuser
#lrwxrwxrwx 1 testuser testuser 15 Oct  6 16:37 testuser -> ../../
ls -l /ftp/home/testuser/ftp/home/testuser/dir/file.txt
#-rw-rw-r-- 1 testuser testuser 16 Nov  6 16:37 file.txt
```